# Merging of Header in Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I encountered a problem in Gridview, I cannot merge the headers if the Gridview has no record, but if the Gridview contain a record, the headers are merging.

Here is my codes that I used to merge the headers in the Gridview

```
protected void grdWorkExperience_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView oGridView = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow oGridViewRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell oTableCell = new TableCell();

            oTableCell.Text = string.Empty;
            oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            oTableCell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            oGridViewRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell);

            oTableCell = new TableCell();
            oTableCell.Text = "Inclusive Dates(mm/dd/yyyy)";
            oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            oTableCell.Font.Bold = true;
            oTableCell.Font.Size = 9;
            oTableCell.Font.Name = "Verdana";
            oTableCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            oTableCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0x33, 0x66, 0xCC);
            oTableCell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            oTableCell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            oGridViewRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell);

            oTableCell = new TableCell();
            oTableCell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 13;
            oGridViewRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell);

            oGridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, oGridViewRow);

        }
    }
```

I placed that function in **onRowCreated** event of Gridview

What should I do to merge the Headers even if the Gridview has no record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code from `OnRowCreated` event to `Load` event of the `Window/Control/Page`

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working I change this code "oGridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, oGridViewRow);" to this "grdWorkExperience.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, oGridViewRow);"
I change oGridView to grdWorkExperience which is the name of the gridview, the line of code which I change is producing this kind of error: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: the gridview is malfunctioning if I put the code in the load event of a page, after I bind the gridview.

Comment: Is there still any other way @Tilak

Comment: You should add row to data bound source. `GridViewRowsCollection` is immutable and cannot be modified.

Comment: what do you mean? It needs that my data source should always have a record? or else, merging of header will not work?

Comment: Data source may be empty. See you are adding record on UI side to data source bound control. Shift this logic to data source side. Add default row to data source.